# Künneth Theorem for $G$-space.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be a right $G$-space and a left $G$ space, respectively, where $G=H \rtimes K$, $H$ a finite group and $K$ a compact Lie group.
Moreover, suppose that the $G$-action on $X$ is free. 
Denote $H_*(-)$ the singular homology with coefficient in a field.

Is $H_*(X \times_G Y )$ isomorphic to $H_*(X) \otimes_{H_*(G)} H_*(Y)$?

Is it possible to prove it without using spectral sequences?

Comment: Could you provide more context for your question? In particular, is it from a course/book you are working through, or is part of your research? If it is a research question it may be more appropriate for mathoverflow.

Comment: Thank you for the info and yeah it is part of my research. I'll post it on mathoverflow then! :)

Comment: What if $X=S^3$, $G$ is a circle and $Y$ is a point?

Comment: [Crossposted on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/350018/21564).